# Uploading content is only supported for 'http' and 'https' schemes

Tags: file-upload, windows-8, winrt-async

i'm trying to upload a file to an ftp server, i'm using this code :

```
Uri uri;
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(serverAddressField.Text.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Invalid URI.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Verify that we are currently not snapped, or that we can unsnap to open the picker.
        if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.Snapped && !ApplicationView.TryUnsnap())
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("File picker cannot be opened in snapped mode. Please unsnap first.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }

        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file == null)
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("No file selected.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }
        PasswordCredential pw = new PasswordCredential();
        pw.Password = "pass";
        pw.UserName = "username";
        BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
        uploader.ServerCredential = pw;
        uploader.Method = "POST";
        uploader.SetRequestHeader("Filename", file.Name);

        UploadOperation upload = uploader.CreateUpload(uri, file);
        Log(String.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}, {2}", file.Name, uri.AbsoluteUri, upload.Guid));

        // Attach progress and completion handlers.
        await HandleUploadAsync(upload, true);
```

but it sends me this exception here :
UploadOperation upload = uploader.CreateUpload(uri, file);
"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Samples.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.exe but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: 'uri': Uploading content is only supported for 'http' and 'https' schemes."

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right there in the exception message.

To quote [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh452975%28v=win.10%29):

> FTP is supported, but only when conducting download operations.

So you can't use `BackgroundUploader` with FTP.

Comment: You can do a regular FTP upload while your application is running, or you can write an HTTP server that accepts uploads and pushes them to the FTP server. There is no way to do a background FTP upload.

Comment: Hello Stephan,thanks for your reply !can you give me an example or tuto for this because i really can't find anything about this purpose.thanks :)

Comment: Something [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx) should work. You'll have to modify it to work asynchronously with WinRT streams, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: but there's no support for FtpWebRequest  in metro applications, can you help me with an example how to adabt it please?

Comment: It looks like Microsoft doesn't support it, so I'd recommend a third-party component [like this one](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ftps.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Async Function FTP_Uploader(ftpURL As String, filename As String, username As String, password As String, file as StorageFile) As Task(Of Boolean)
        Try
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(ftpURL + "/" + filename)
            request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Trim(), password.Trim())
            request.Method = "STOR"
            Dim buffer As Byte() = ReadFiletoBinary(filename, file)
            Dim requestStream As Stream = Await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()
            Await requestStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            Await requestStream.FlushAsync()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
End Function

Public Shared Async Function ReadFileToBinary(ByVal filename As String, file As StorageFile) As Task(Of Byte())

        Dim readStream As IRandomAccessStream = Await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)
        Dim inputStream As IInputStream = readStream.GetInputStreamAt(0)

        Dim dataReader As DataReader = New DataReader(inputStream)
        Dim numBytesLoaded As UInt64 = Await dataReader.LoadAsync(Convert.ToUInt64(readStream.Size))

        Dim i As UInt64
        Dim b As Byte
        Dim returnvalue(numBytesLoaded) As Byte

        While i < numBytesLoaded
            inputStream = readStream.GetInputStreamAt(i)
            b = dataReader.ReadByte()
            returnvalue(i) = b
            i = i + 1
        End While

        readStream.Dispose()
        inputStream.Dispose()
        dataReader.Dispose()
        Return returnvalue

End Function
```

Had the same issue, this worked for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I stubled upon the same problem. After a day of work I got it to work with the WebRequest class.

A fully working application with download functionality is available here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWindowsStoreAppFTPDownloa-88a90bd9

I modified this code to enable uploading to the server too.

This is for uploading files:

```cs
public async Task UploadFTPFileAsync(Uri destination, StorageFile targetFile)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(destination);
    request.Credentials = Credentials;
    request.Method = "STOR";

    using (var requestStream = (await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
    using (var stream = await targetFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
    }
}
```

And this is for creating directories:

```cs
public async Task CreateFTPDirectoryAsync(Uri directory)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(directory);
    request.Credentials = Credentials;
    request.Method = "MKD";

    using (var response = (await request.GetResponseAsync()))
    {
        //flush
        //using will call the (hidden!) close method, which will finish the request.
    }
}
```

`request.Credentials` can be filled with NetworkCredential, like this:

```cs
private string strFtpAccount;
private string strFtpPassword;
private string strFtpDomain;

public ICredentials Credentials
{
    get
    {
        return new NetworkCredential(strFtpAccount, strFtpPassword, strFtpDomain);
    }
}
```